# Filtering a range with Power Query including empty cells

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table which looks like this:

| ID Number | Content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 |
| 2 | row2 |
|  | row3 |
| 7 | row4 |
|  | row5 |
|  | row6 |
| 8 | row7 |
| 10 | row8 |
| 12 | row9 |
| 14 | row10 |

I would like to filter column "ID Number" by number range in Power Query, but including empty rows in between.

Query: ID Number > 2 and ID Number < 8

Numbers are increasing moving down but there might be gaps in numbering.

Result should be as follows:

| ID Number | Content |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | row2 |
|  | row3 |
| 7 | row4 |
|  | row5 |
|  | row6 |
| 8 | row7 |

How can it be done with Power Query? when I do standard filtering it filters out the blanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a helper column which fills down and filter on that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]